# Foursquare api nearby places

Tags: ios, objective-c, foursquare

I am Newbie to programming field.My task is to enter latitude & longitude in text boxes and when i click a button , should show nearby places.i have this client id and secret. can anyone tell as to how to go ahead about this. i mean coding.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Foursquare Developer site,it will be useful for you(https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries) 
and for showing nearby places based on the latitude and longitude 
(https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2).Add the Foursquare files into your project and check with the authentication in your view controller
    The below method is used to show the nearby places,

```
+(void)searchVenuesNearByLatitude:(NSString*)lat
                    longitude:(NSString*)lon
                   accuracyLL:(NSString*)accuracyLL
                     altitude:(NSString*)altitude
                  accuracyAlt:(NSString*)accuracyAlt
                        query:(NSString*)query
                        limit:(NSString*)limit
                       intent:(NSString*)intent
                     callback:(Foursquare2Callback)callback;
```